# Chrome Web Store Publish API setup issue: You can’t sign in because [App_name] sent an invalid request...Error 400: invalid_request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-developers-console, chrome-web-store, webstore

I am trying to use Chrome Web Store API for the first time.

I am following the steps given [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/using_webstore_api/) verbatim

Firstly I don't understand why it asks me to select Application type as Desktop App when it is instruction manual for Chrome extension.

This is the test url which they want me to paste on browser after getting the CLIENT_ID value.

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore&client_id=$CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob

Second The error I get is this:

```
Access blocked: [App_name]’s request is invalid

ishandutta2007@gmail.com
You can’t sign in because [App_name] sent an invalid request. You can try again later, or contact the developer about this issue. Learn more about this error
If you are a developer of [App_name], see error details.
Error 400: invalid_request
```

Given that we don't need CLIENT_SECRET in the test url which they provide and I tried creating an app with Application type as Chrome extension as well but I get the same error.

Things which my supervisor(ie chatGPT) asked me to double check are:

1. have selected the correct application type
2. provided the correct App ID or Extension ID.
3. have enabled the Chrome Web Store API in the Google Cloud Console.
4. OAuth2 client ID you are using has the appropriate permissions.

For (1) I already have questions as mentioned above and for (4) I was not asked while creating credentials.